# Can anyone suggest me any network design scnario to test cisco knowledge

Tags: networking, cisco

I am learning CCNA and was using packet tracer to experiment stuff.

Is there any way where i can get the sample network scenario so that i can try to emulate in packet tracer uisng all ACL, VLAN OSPF , NAT

i want to simulate ISP , WAN link , etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GNS3](http://gns3.net/) is a popular Graphical Network Simulator. I highly recommend their [quick start guide](http://geexhq.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/11/simulating-network-lab.pdf). You might want to take a look at their [forum](http://www.gns3.net/phpBB/), where you can download complete labs etc.

Note that you are legally required to have (licensed) IOS software.
Happy hunting! :)